Breaking one leg of diamond inheritance problem: alternatives?
I am contributing some pieces to a large software project in C++. Here's a problem I'm running into.
We already have in the repository
(1) A.h
class A : public X, public Y, public Z
{
  ...
} 

(2) B.h
template <bool is_ad>
class BTempl: public A
{
  ...
}

(3) C.h
template <bool is_ad>
class CTempl: public BTempl<is_ad>
{
  ...
}

(4) D.h
template <bool is_ad>
class DTempl: public CTempl<is_ad>
{
  ...
}

Now suppose I need some other functionality in D.C which is best introduced through, say, E.C and E.h. By necessity E.h needs to inherit from A.h which contains methods, naming conventions, etc., that cannot be done without:
(5) E.h
template <bool is_ad>
class ETempl: public A
{
  ...
}

and then modify D.h like this:
template <bool is_ad>
class DTempl: public CTempl<is_ad>, public ETempl<is_ad>
{
  ...
}

Of course, this results in the dreaded diamond problem, whereby I end up with multiple compilation errors of the type
error: non-static member 'getParam' found in multiple base-class subobjects of type 'X2':
    class DTempl<false> -> CTempl<false> -> BTempl<false> -> class A -> class X -> class X1 -> class X2
    class DTempl<false> -> ETempl<false> -> class A -> class X -> class X1 -> class X2

The usual way to solve this would be through virtual inheritance. That is, I would normally use the following in the header files instead:
template <bool is_ad>
class ETempl: virtual public A
{
  ...
}

template <bool is_ad>
class CTempl: virtual public BTempl<is_ad>
{
  // This is not allowed for my purposes; see below.
}

But the problem is that because this is a large software project, I am not allowed to make such changes to C.h -- or would at best be allowed to make minimal changes that do not affect such dependencies and inheritances. Multiple other classes would inherit from C.h. I tried and this would mess many other things up, giving me other kinds of compilation errors. Likewise I am not allowed to modify the dependencies in A, B, or other source and header files.
Is there a good way to "break only one leg" of this inheritance problem? Namely, I would still like E to inherit from A, but I only want D to inherit whatever is necessary from E. All the duplicate methods (such as "getParam" above) should be inherited only once, preferably via C. The methods that E would need to inherit from A are too numerous to list, and I am presumably not allowed to modify A to stop D from inheriting these methods from A via E.
One thing I tried to fix this would be to put what was supposed to be in E.C and E.h directly into D.C and D.h, or for that matter C.C and C.h and then let D inherit everything from C. Because of peculiarities of what is involved in the code, I would however end up with circular dependencies such as the following (the code would compile successfully but runs result in immediate failures), because D would need to access variables such as P immediately upon initialization:
*** ERROR ***
      Cyclic dependency detected in object ordering:
P <- Q <- R <- S <- P

Another thing I tried is delegation as opposed to inheritance: in D.h I would only inherit from C, but include a line
E _e;

Then in D.C I would call functions and quantities in E according to
_e.myfunc(x);
std::cout << _e._variable << std::endl;

where in E I would define the functions in the following manner:
void myfunc(int y)

The code in such a case would compile and run normally on my local machine as well as another HPC cluster I have access to, but not on the GitHub compiler that is needed to merge the code, which would give me compilation errors such as
undefined reference to `ETempl<false>::myfunc(int)'

so I presume delegation is ruled out for practical purposes.

Yes there is an alternative called CRTP mixin. In general you should only inherit from abstract baseclasses. Then declare implementations of these interfaces as template classes. And then "derive" your own class from that template class using your own class name as template argument. Multiple inheritance from multiple classes like the current code base does (just for code reuse) is not a good pattern.

Run away from that place as fast as you can.

@n.m.couldbeanAI You mean codebase right? ;)

@Pepijn Kramer template <class T> CTempl: virtual public BTempl<T> already looks like they have one going somewhere there.
CRTP if you want be equally crazy as they are (in extreme case diamond problem expands to CRTP too). One can usie bridges and adaptors instead of inheritance

@n.m.couldbeanAI Unfortunately I am not allowed to really change the underlying structure of this massive code as a contributor. I cannot even edit C.h and use template <class T> CTempl: virtual public BTempl<T> there; as I noted above, this would cause other errors.

@PepijnKramer I looked some docs and I'm utterly confused. How should this be implemented in my example?

So instead of class DTempl: public CTempl<is_ad>, public ETempl<is_ad> you'll have  some class DTempl: public CTempl<is_ad>, public EMixin<DTempl>, where EMixin would add functionality to DTempl, accessing what CTempl contains via  static_cast<DTempl*>(this). EMixin not derived from  whole chain, although you may need some classfor declarations in certain cases. Or something similar, depending what new functionality is. It's what they actually had to do much earler.

This question is better addressed by someone in your organization who's familiar with the code base and the design decisions underlying that (horrible) class hierarchy. Whoever's telling you "you can't do that" should also be telling you "here's now to do it".

Your last approach seems reasonable. I woud investigate the root cause of compile error. Either you are missing something, or the compiler is defect(in which case nobody can help). I assume that you know template function definition must be present at instantiation site.

I hope this example helps you to understand what I mean.
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

// start by declaring some abstract baseclasses
// or interfacs. Interfaces are good for a lot of things
// like dependency injection (and thus also for unit testing)

class XInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~XInterface() = default;
    virtual void DoX() = 0;
};

class YInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~YInterface() = default;
    virtual void DoY() = 0;
};

class ZInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~ZInterface() = default;
    virtual void DoZ() = 0;
};

// Then provide some default implementations. 
// these are the mixin classes
// they are templated to create unique base classes
// that provide the implementation for exactly one interface
// based on the derived class (CRTP pattern)
// So you will never get diamond inheritance
// but you will have reusable source code
// kind of like source code building blocks

template<typename derived_t>
class XImpl : public XInterface
{
public:
    void DoX() override
    {
        std::cout << typeid(XImpl).name() << "::X\n";
    }
};

template<typename derived_t>
class YImpl : public YInterface
{
public:
    void DoY() override
    {
        std::cout << typeid(YImpl).name() << "::Y\n";
    }
};

template<typename derived_t>
class ZImpl : public ZInterface
{
public:
    void DoZ() override
    {
        std::cout << typeid(ZImpl).name() << "::Z\n";
    }
};

// Then you can make "combination classes"
// such a combination class will NOT have the diamond problem
// XImpl<XY> will be a unique new class name
// and so will YImpl<XY>
class XY :
    public XImpl<XY>,
    public YImpl<XY>
{
};

class XYZ  :
    public XImpl<XYZ>, // XImpl<XYZ> is not the same type as XImpl<XY>
    public YImpl<XYZ>,
    public ZImpl<XYZ>
{
};

int main()
{
    XY xy{};
    xy.DoX();
    xy.DoY();

    XYZ xyz{};
    xyz.DoX();
    xyz.DoY();
    xyz.DoZ();
}


Thank you. Gives me a clearer idea. My question at this point is: which files should each of these classes reside? Do I need to use things like typeid(XImpl).func() whenever I need to call a function from X?
Remember that (with the naming as in the original post) I cannot modify anything in A, B, C, X, Y, and Z that pertains to linkage, inheritance, and such. So where should the interfaces be? I could modify D to a bigger extent so that it gets what it needs from E, but because D uses numerous functions from A, B, and C this will be hell if I need to add typeid(XImpl) everywhere...

The interface declarations go into interface header files (most publicly accessible files), the implementations go in their own header files (which is normal for templates).  The typeid is never needed in practice I added it to show you that you end up with unique class names because of the templates. Also you can still create your own AImpl which either aggregates (or even inherits) from the original A class.
